# Como mostrar uma notificação na tela sem afetar a aplicação ativa

Tags: c#

Como faço para mostrar uma notificação sem afetar a aplicação ativa?
Resumindo, quero que a notificação seja exibida na tela e que a aplicação ativa não perca o foco, ou se for uma aplicação de tela cheia, quero que a mesma não seja minimizada.

Comment: Que tipo de notificação?

Comment: Até onde sei, não é possível. Se você der o foco à sua aplicação, você minimiza automaticamente a aplicação que estiver na tela no momento (se ela estiver em tela cheia). Você pode usar a API do Windows, com chamadas direto às DLL's do sistema, mas não é certo que sua mensagem irá aparecer sem minimizar a aplicação em tela cheia. Isso vale mesmo para mensagens do tipo *toltips* na bandeja do lado do relógio. Fica ainda mais incerto se a aplicação em tela cheia usar aceleração 3D. Boa sorte.

Comment: Suspenderam por não estar claro mais o autor do comentário acima entendeu... Eu que não entendi a suspensão. Obrigado @Renan, achei uma forma de fazer isto, pesquisei um pouco mais e encontrei: [GrowlWPFNotification](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/499241/Growl-Alike-WPF-Notifications)

Comment: @JonathanScripter votie para reabrir. Espero que a pergunta seja reaberta, para que você possa compartilhar sua solução.

Comment: Também votei para reabrir

Comment: Como está fazendo isso ? Wpf ? windows forms ..especifique que tipo de notificação deseja e qual método está utilizando, da pra fazer de varias formas. Mas respondendo sua pergunta pra mostrar uma notificação sem afetar a aplicação ativa você deve rodar em uma Thread separada, Sugiro que Crie uma nova Task e de um Invoke no objeto que deseja mostrar.

Comment: Acredito que seja possível (meio que na gambiarra), mas não possuo muito conhecimento de C# e API do Windows para fornecer um exemplo, talvez você pude-se criar a sua própria notificação em um projeto separado, ou seja ele ser  um `.exe` e seria chamado pelo seu aplicativo principal. Nota: reforço que não tenho conhecimentos sobre C# para desenvolvimento Desktop.

Comment: Notificação pode ser entendido de varias maneiras, e depende do OS e do gerenciador de desktop em questão (quando aplicável). Fora isso, tem mais uma série de coisas. Creio que a pergunta possa ser editada e melhorada com os detalhes que já foram pedidos neste e em outros comentários.

Answer (score 1):

Não entendi muito bem sua pergunta mas me parece que está desenvolvendo uma aplicação windows form.
Você poderia fazer uma notificação daquelas que aparecem na barra de tarefas com o código abaixo:

```
        NotifyIcon notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
        notifyIcon.Visible = true;
        notifyIcon.Icon = SystemIcons.Information;
        notifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = "Título";
        notifyIcon.BalloonTipText = "Texto da Notificação";
        notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(30000);
```

Espero ter ajudado. Se não é isso que quer explique melhor por favor.